# React Native Stop ScrollView event after refreshcontrol fires

Tags: react-native

I am using React-Native version 0.59.9.

I have a ScrollView which has a RefreshControl inside it.

```
     <ScrollView
      ref="_scrollView"

      onScrollEndDrag={({ nativeEvent }) => {
        if (this.isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {

          console.log("scrolling")

        }
      }}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.state.loading}
          onRefresh={() =>{this.preventDefault=true; this.onRefresh()}}
          tintColor="#FBE40D"
          progressBackgroundColor="#FBE40D"
        />
      }
    >
```

When I try to refresh the page by pulling it down (using `RefreshControl`), then along with `onRefresh` method, the `onScrollEndDrag` event is also getting fired.

What's interesting is that, it is happening only in ios and not on Android.
Is there a way I can stop the `onScrollEndDrag` if the `onRefresh` has already triggered?

(Clearly, the `preventDefault` is not working).

Please let me know if I can provide more details.

Comment: Hi Shibasis, have you manged to find a solution to this problem?